# Angular provider and $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

if in provider `$get` I inject `$http` and do sam AJAX (for configuration) do I have sure any operation on this `service` will be done after requests end?

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: `$get` functions are invoked in the AngularJS run phase after all configuration is complete. No further system configuration is allowed during application run time. Services that invoke asynchronous methods in their construction function, must use promises to prevent race conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$http returns a promise. If you want to execute some code on receiving a response please put it inside the then method callback of said promise.